# Does "Before [month]" include that month?

Tags: meaning-in-context, time

For example, if someone said

> They want it to be finished before September.

Does that mean the work should be finished by Aug 31 or Sep 30 at least?

Comment: Work should be completed by or before August 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the work should be finished by August 31st.

Think about it like any other time frame. If you asked me to come to your house *before* 2:00 PM, I think you'd be mad if I came at 2:59 PM.